# Error: Support for running under Java 16 requires Gradle 7, which will be supported in ForgeGradle 5

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-forge

I am using this -> https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/
(forge documentation)

now I'm on this point:

> Generating IDE Launch/Run Configurations:

> For IntelliJ, run the genIntellijRuns gradle task (gradlew genIntellijRuns).

And this what i have:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\T\Desktop\mods\Dcraft\build.gradle' line: 10

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Dcraft'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'.
   > Found java version 17.0.1. Versions 16 and newer are not supported yet.
     Note: Support for running under Java 16 requires Gradle 7, which will be supported in ForgeGradle 5.
```

line 10 in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'
```

I already tried to google for solutions and download jdk 15.0.2, but it didn't help...
I think ForgeGradle 5 will help me, but I don't know how to install it.
Please help me with this problem.

PS. I have latest version java, jdk 17.0.1, gradle 7 and forge mdk 1.16.5-36.1.20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded jdk version to 15.0.2 and this helped to solve problem.

Comment: I recommend downgrading to Java 11 instead, Java versions 12 - 16 or short-term support versions, while 11 and 17 are long-term support versions. Java 15 ceased to be supported little more than a year ago (and Java 16 ceased to be supported when Java 17 was released).